# Why does lateinit work on Object type but not primitive type?

Tags: kotlin

[This answer says that Object types use the null value on lateinits of Object type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38761294/6733153). Can someone elaborate on this? What do they mean by "uses the null value"?

Furthermore it says "For primitive types, there is no such value" - why is there no

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the JVM, which was historically the first platform targeted by Kotlin, there is a distinction between the [primitive types](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Primitive_Types) and classes, or object types.

They have different runtime representations: a primitive value is stored directly in the field, which can only hold one of the corresponding primitive type values (e.g. only `true` and `false` for `boolean`) and has no special representation for a *missing value*. In comparison, a class-typed field stores an indirect *reference* to an instance that is allocated somewhere in the heap, and a class-typed field can hold a special `null` reference that doesn't point to any instance.

The Kotlin `lateinit` properties are compiled to a single field and they internally use the `null` value to indicate that the property has not yet been initialized. As primitive-typed JVM fields can't have a `null` value, Kotlin doesn't allow `lateinit` properties of types that are normally [mapped to Java primitives](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types), as that would require a different representation, and no acceptable solution existed, as the other answer says.

Instead, you can use [`by Delegates.notNull()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205389/difference-between-delegates-notnull-and-lateinit-kotlin) to achieve similar behavior with the mapped types.