# How To Intialize an Integer In Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I Am Trying To Send The Data To Another Using Shared Preferences And When i Send The the value i get An Exception like this

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.medicaltimetableapp, PID: 27357
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Property s_year should be initialized before get.
    at kotlin.properties.NotNullVar.getValue(Delegates.kt:62)
    at com.example.medicaltimetableapp.Add$onCreate$7.onClick(Add.kt:177)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6300)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24941)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

Here is The s_year declaration code

`var s_year by Delegates.notNull<Int>()`

I Am Assigning It To A Value

```
 day.setOnClickListener {
        val dpt = DatePickerDialog(
            this@Add,
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, mYear, mMonth, mDay ->
                mMonth
                var month = mMonth
                Toast.makeText(this@Add, "$mYear$month$mDay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
          //THIS IS THE VALUE        
   s_year = mYear ////// VALUE
                s_Month = mMonth+1
                s_Day = mDay
            }, year, month, daay
        )

        dpt.show()
    }
```

Comment: `var s_year : Int by Delegates.notNull()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer Declaration is perfect.. Make sure your DatePickerDialog code is correct and it correctly assign the value to s_year integer or not.. Check my below code for your reference..

```
var s_year by Delegates.notNull<Int>()
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    mMessageEditText!!.setOnClickListener {
        val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            // Display Selected date in TextView
            mMessageEditText!!.setText("$dayOfMonth $month $year")
            s_year = year
        }, year, month, day)
        dpd.show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are using `s_year` before it gets initialized and its defined as `notNull`, Since its only getting initialized inside `OnDateSetListener` . So you should avoid it. `Delegates.notNull()` and `lateinit` are quite similar since you can not use `lateinit` with primitive types and we do check `::variableName.isInitialized` for lateinit property. [have a look at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205389/difference-between-delegates-notnull-and-lateinit-kotlin)

Alternatively you can just use `var s_year: Int?=null` and use it with safety operator `?`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use 'lateinit', if u are setting the value later.

use it as:

```
private lateinit var s_year : Int
btnLogin.setOnClickListener { 
        s_year = Random(5);  
    }
```

or u can use var with its initial/ default value:

```
private var s_year : Int = 0
```

Comment: when giving an answer, it's always a good idea to test it first to make sure it'll work. if you had typed `private lateinit var s_year : Int` in to your IDE, you would see that this isn't a valid answer :)

Comment: late init can't used on Int